# Getting "Signature validation failed. Reference validation failed" when trying to validate saml 2.0 response

Tags: xml, x509certificate, saml-2.0

I'm trying to validate my saml response on the samltool.com website and I keep getting "Signature validation failed. Reference validation failed".  I've searched the web and found some suggestions, however it either doesn't fix the error or it creates new errors.

Here is my response, any suggestions would be appreciated

```
<samlp2:Response xmlns:samlp2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" ID="SAML-027a0db7-ecd3-464e-b4e0-400870b6ab5a" IssueInstant="2020-11-19T10:41:21Z" Destination="[Destination]">
  <samlp2:Status>
    <samlp2:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp2:Status>
  <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_83213680-19ae-4e12-8ccd-d24a818ec1a6" IssueInstant="2020-11-19T16:41:21.370Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer>[Issuer]</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:Signature xmlns:saml2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <saml2:SignedInfo>
        <saml2:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <saml2:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <saml2:Reference URI="#_83213680-19ae-4e12-8ccd-d24a818ec1a6">
          <saml2:Transforms>
            <saml2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <saml2:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </saml2:Transforms>
          <saml2:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <saml2:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</saml2:DigestValue>
        </saml2:Reference>
      </saml2:SignedInfo>
      <saml2:SignatureValue>[SignatureValue]</saml2:SignatureValue>
      <saml2:KeyInfo>
        <saml2:X509Data>
          <saml2:X509Certificate>[X509Cert]</saml2:X509Certificate>
        </saml2:X509Data>
      </saml2:KeyInfo>
    </saml2:Signature>
    <saml2:Subject>
      <saml2:NameID>[emailId]</saml2:NameID>
      <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData Address="[ipaddress]" NotOnOrAfter="2020-11-29T06:00:00.000Z" Recipient="[Recipient]"/>
      </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
    <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2020-11-19T16:41:21.370Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-11-29T06:00:00.000Z">
      <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml2:Audience>[SPEntityId]</saml2:Audience>
      </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml2:Conditions>
    <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-11-19T16:41:21.370Z">
      <saml2:AuthnContext>
        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PreviousSession</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml2:AuthnContext>
    </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="firstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[firstName]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="lastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[lastName]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="emailId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[emailId]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="custCode" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[custCode]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="phone" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[phone]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
      <saml2:Attribute Name="ssoId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
        <saml2:AttributeValue>[ssoId]</saml2:AttributeValue>
      </saml2:Attribute>
    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
  </saml2:Assertion>
</samlp2:Response>
```

Comment: As you can see from the answer below I'm just moving things around at this point to see if something works

Answer (score 0):

I added the issuer and signature outside of the response but before the status and now I get "Found an invalid Signed Element. SAML Response rejected"

```
<samlp2:Response Version="2.0" ID="SAML-18b9737d-5969-4231-a074-0ff5ca3ab0df" IssueInstant="2020-11-19T01:00:24Z" Destination="[Destination]" xmlns:samlp2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.lacitizens.com</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_1a4fdd97-53f3-4676-aec3-e00213f226eb"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>[SignatureValue]</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>[X509Certificate]</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature>  
  <samlp2:Status>
    <samlp2:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp2:Status>
 <saml2:Assertion ID="_1a4fdd97-53f3-4676-aec3-e00213f226eb" IssueInstant="2020-11-19T19:00:24.563Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:Issuer>https://www.lacitizens.com</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_1a4fdd97-53f3-4676-aec3-e00213f226eb"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>[SignatureValue]</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>[X509Certificate]</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID>[emailId]</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData Address="[ipaddress]" NotOnOrAfter="2020-11-29T06:00:00.000Z" Recipient="[recipient]" /></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2020-11-19T19:00:24.563Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-11-29T06:00:00.000Z"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>[audience]</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-11-19T19:00:24.563Z"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PreviousSession</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement><saml2:Attribute Name="firstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[firstName]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="lastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[lastName]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="emailId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[emailId]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="custCode" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[custCode]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="phone" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[phone]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="ssoId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"><saml2:AttributeValue>[ssoId]</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion>
</samlp2:Response>
```